# Meteor How to get ONE element from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my MongoDatabase i have 5 elements.

First the _id then a follower with his idfollower and a following with his idfollowing.

now im trying to get only the IDFOLLOWING element

```
var userid = Relationships.findOne({follower: Meteor.user().username}).idfollowing;
```

this works!

Now i got 5 entries in the Database and the code only shows me 1 ID not 5

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/collections - you want `.find`

Comment: Now the console says undefined

Comment: It's undefined because `.find` returns a cursor pointing to the results and `.fetch()` will return all the results as an array of objects. Try `Relationships.find({follower: Meteor.user().username}).fetch()` Then iterate through the array to extract `idfollowing`.

Comment: Well i tried to do it but i dont get it how to iterate through the array to get `idfollowing`  ... :/

Comment: David's answer is great for this case. But if you don't know how to iterate over arrays just in general, I suggest looking at some basic JavaScript tutorials to get familiar with object, arrays, loops, functions, etc.

Comment: Yea ok im new in Meteor and javascript thats why some is really hard to understand for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check out the online tutorials at Codecademy: https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript The Discover Meteor book is also a must-have for learning Meteor. You will need to have a decent understanding of some JS fundamentals first since in general explanations and examples in documentation can be scarce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
// fetch an array of relationships where the current user is the follower
var selector = {follower: Meteor.user().username};
var relationships = Relationships.find(selector).fetch();

// create an array of ids? by extracting the idfollowing values from relationships
var userIds = _.pluck(relationships, 'idfollowing');
```

Here's the documentation for:

- [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck)
- [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)
- [fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch)

Comment: Well this looks great! But i need to get the IDs not in a array the have to be alone because i want to get the Profile pictures from the users with the ID `var images = Images.find({profilekey: userIds});  return images;`

Comment: It's hard to say without a more in-depth knowledge of your application. Maybe `Images.find({profilekey: {$in: userIds}})`? That would get you a cursor for all images where the `profilekey` matches any of the `userIds`.

Comment: Yea nice i got it ! Thanks :)